# VMWare Workstation 16 Windows 10 not enough physical memory is available to power on this virtual machine

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, vmware

Workstation 16.1.0
windows 10 64bit
8GB RAM

VM settings:

[image]

Error message:

[image]

Steps tried to resolve:

- Run as Administrator
- Tried `vmmon.disableHostParameters = “TRUE”` in config.ini.

Comment: What machine / operating system is the Image?  You should be able to run 1 machine plus the host easily for a common guest system.  I assume you have enabled Hardware Virtualization in BIOS,

Comment: Are you sure you have 8GB ram available? Looking at your VM's settings, you have only 4.6GB ram available to dedicate, while you configured to use 4GB. This leaves an extremely low amount of memory for host OS to use, and if used, you might not be able to run this machine.

Comment: When looking at `performance/memory` in `Task Manager`, how much available RAM do you currently have, and what is the maximum supported by your machine?

Comment: can you drop your email or skye please @Pizza